# Git: How to merge branch to master locally and on Github?

Tags: git, github

I have a project with a master branch. So I created another branch dev and later uploaded it to Github. Finished the work in the dev branch, uploaded it to Github and merged it to master locally. Merged it to master on Github also. Now when I run `git status` on master branch locally, it says your branch is ahead of `origin/master` by 3 commits. In the dev branch, I had 3 commits.

Now what to do? Master branch on Github is already updated as I had merged dev branch to it but now there is no sync between master on Github and master locally. If I git push locally, it will add duplicate commits to master on Github.

Comment: You need to merge in one repository and then use `git push` or `git pull` to sync the local and remote repositories. At the moment you have two merges between master and development that occurred at two different times.

Comment: If you are sure that the commit are in Github, you can do `git rebase origin/master` while on the `master` branch.

Comment: Run `git fetch` and then `git status` again. What do you see now?

Comment: @Jona It says Current branch master is up to date.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness After running `git fetch`, it says your branch is behind `origin/master` and says use `git pull`. Earlier it was ahead of `origin/master` and asked to use `git push`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you merge both branches remotely and locally, your two destinations are not aware of this change.

To make your local-master aware that origin/master also has the same commits, simply run:

```
git pull
```

:)